# Как написать регулярку для поиска в тексте определенных смайликов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярку для поиска в тексте следующих смайликов: `[':)', ':-)', ':(', ':-(', ':o', ':-o']`. Регулярку я написала, но она захватывает и другие смайлы вроде `:D`. Помогите этого избежать.

Код:

```py
import re

smileys = [':)', ':-)', ':(', ':-(', ':o', ':-o']
template = '(:-?.|o|[()])'
for s in smileys:
    print(re.match(template, s))
```

Comment: например, так  `(:-?[o()])`

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятно стало :)

Comment: вы можете принять ответ, нажав галочку слева. Это оставит информацию потомкам, что ответ подошел :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться таким выражением

```
(:-?[o()])
```

двоеточие, возможный дефис, один из символов `o()`